# Issue with class access specifier

Tags: java, spring, class

I have a file Test.java with contents as below:

```
class MyClass{
   private String myMember;

   public String getMyMember(){ return this.myMember;}
   public void setMyMember(final String myMember){this.myMember = myMember;}
}

public class Test implements Tasklet{
         public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    // getting error here

   List<MyClass> myClassList= this.myJdbcTemplate.query(myQuery,
        ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyClass.class));

   return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }

}
```

Tasklet is a spring batch interface.

I am getting error as below:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.mypackage.MyClass]: Is the constructor accessible?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException
```

What is the reason for the error ?

How to resolve it ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass` should be `public` and optionally should expose a default constructor:

```
public class MyClass() {
    public MyClass() {

    }
}
```

You're expecting the `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` to return a `List<MyClass>` while `MyClass` is package private.

Spring's `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` won't be aware of the existence of `MyClass` if `MyClass` is not public.

Comment: Won't the class be package private and so accessible from anywhere in the package ?

Comment: When ommiting `public` it will be package-private, yes.

Comment: @Vicky Spring isn't in your package.  A class from `Spring` is trying to invoke the constructor.

Comment: So my other class is also in the same package. Then why am I unable to access ? Can you please elaborate your answer giving reason for the error to better understand the concepts.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: "A class from Spring" ???? The class is in my package and it implements a spring interface. Where does spring come into picture here ?

Comment: `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` is not within the same package and your trying to use the `MyClass` within it.

Comment: @Vicky I take it your question to me has been answered?